# How to change color of outliers when using geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made several different attempts to change the fill color of the outliers for a boxplot I'm constructing, to no avail. Any help is appreciated. This is my code so far...

```
# Load the dataset.
data <- read.csv("C:\\School\\Statistics\\bearWeight.csv")

# Initialize dataframe variable for both WEIGHT & Relative Frequency
WEIGHT <- data$WEIGHT
RelativeFrequency <- data$Relative.Frequency

# Load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

bearWeightBoxPlot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=WEIGHT, y=RelativeFrequency, group = 1))

bearWeightBoxPlot <- bearWeightBoxPlot + 
  geom_boxplot(colour = "#3366FF", outlier.colour = "black", 
               outlier.shape = 24, outlier.fill = "red", outlier.size = 3)

bearWeightBoxPlot <- bearWeightBoxPlot + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2) + 
  coord_flip()

plot(bearWeightBoxPlot)
```

Answer (score 3):

We need the argument `outlier.fill` and shapes from 21 to 25.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "black",
                 outlier.shape = 24,
                 outlier.fill = "red",
                 outlier.size = 3 # not actually needed
                 )
```

[image]

---

An overview about possible shapes can be found here: [www.cookbook-r.com](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the shape of outliers to be colored by fill aesthetic (shape = 21 to fill the shape with chosen fill)

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Species,Sepal.Width,fill="skyblue1"))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 21)
```

[image]