# Changing the outliers color in a box plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

I wanna change the colors of the outliers of the box plots, to make them correspond to the color of period. I tried several ways, but some of them add another legend to the graph. Can anyone help me ? Here is the code and the graph that I currently get with it and the final graph that I want :

```
ggplot(dat_bee_merged, aes(x = factor(region), y = colony_loss_proportion)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(period))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = median(dat_bee_merged$colony_loss_proportion), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Climatic Regions", y = "Normalized colony loss", fill = "period") +
  ggtitle("Honeybee colony loss across different climatic regions and periods")
  theme_minimal()
```

**Graph that I get:**
[image: Graph that I get]

**Graph that I want:**
[image: Graph that I want]

**My data set:**
[image: My data set]

Comment: What's the difference in the two pictures exactly ?  i don't clearly get the message in the "correspond to the color of period" in the pictures. kindly edit the post to include more detailed explanation

Comment: it would also be nice if you include a small version of the data you are using so people can test their solutions and you can see if it produces your desired output. `dput()` is a friend. [Some examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Derf it would be nice to maybe get the data.
You could however try the following code stated in:
[How to change color of outliers when using geom_boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259077/how-to-change-color-of-outliers-when-using-geom-boxplot)
by @Markus:

```r
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(period)), 
               outlier.colour = "black",
               outlier.shape = 24,
               outlier.fill = "red",
               outlier.size = 3)
```

Hope that helps.

Based on your modifications I slightly modified my script:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(carb), y = qsec)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(am)), 
               outlier.colour = "black",
               outlier.shape = 21,
               # outlier.fill = NA,
               outlier.size = 2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = median(mtcars$qsec), color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  labs(x = "carb", y = "disp", fill = "am") +
  ggtitle("mtcars") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Sorry the question was incomplete. I am modifying it rn. Thank you for your time folks !

Comment: It works ! thank you so much :)

Comment: Would you mind giving me an upvote and accepting the answer if you are satisfied, for future users?